# How to count number of columns using Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, groovy, geb

Let's assume the following situation:

[image]

Code for this situation:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.element {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="box">
        <div class="element">element 1</div>
        <div class="element">element 2</div>
        <div class="element">element 3</div>
        <div class="element">element 4</div>
        <div class="element">element 5</div>
        <div class="element">element 6</div>
        <div class="element">element 7</div>
        <div class="element">element 8</div>
        <div class="element">element 9</div>
        <div class="element">element 10</div>
     </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

width set to 50% - 2 columns
width set to 33% - 3 columns

and the question is: how to count number of columns using Selenium except reading width value :)

Page is written in RWD and number of columns will depend on width of page for given device

Comment: Could you just get them all and group by their clientLeft property?

Comment: I added an id to each element, and when I execute document.getElementById("elementID").clientLeft always returns 0

Comment: Maybe try calling `getLocation()` on each web element? `$('.element')*.location`

Comment: ok, I found solution: `document.getElementById("elementID").getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: @tim_yates thank you for some idea of the answer